# Why isn't this question closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The summary of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/why-my-phone-battery-has-four-terminal-what-is-the-use-of-the-fourth) question is:

> I have a LG Optimus One (P500). For sometime I am wondering why my phone's battery has four terminals.

I don't think this question is related to Android at all. Even my 7 years old Motorola phone running Java based OS has similar battery.

This question is similar to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/difference-between-armv6-armv7-processors) question and looks like its going to be closed any moment.

Why hasn't the question been closed but rather received so many up-votes?

Comment: maybe it caught interest for "what's the 4th connector good for spedifically with Android" (answer maybe: NFC antenna, might as well be related to [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25480/why-is-the-nfc-in-the-galaxy-nexus-battery) one)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bad question per se, just *not quite* on topic for us.

However it's also not fully off-topic (there is an Android hardware element to it) and it does have a pretty well written question and informative, well-written answers.

Personally I haven't voted to close it, I don't think it's doing any harm and is interesting and informative for people who are interested in how their device works.

Comment: I agree. It's a grey area kind of question. At the least, it is interesting and related to Android.

Answer (score 1):

It's got two Close votes at the moment.

Why is it getting upvoted? This is the perpetual meta question on just about all of the Stack Exchange sites. This on-topic Q&A stuff is hard.

(For what it's worth, I'd already voted to close both of those.)

Comment: Hmm! so you and I are the one wise ones, who voted to close it down :)